# Entity Container and Model generation in different assemblies

Tags: assemblies, linq-to-entities

I'm doing some refactoring and am trying to reuse my genertated entity models.  My application has a few assemblies, one being my outward facing public types (API) and one containing implementations of providers (such as the log).

I'd like to split the generation of the entities and models so that the entities will be in the API assembly and the container will be in the implementation assembly.  Is this possible?

---

Is possible.  This is how I did it.

- Assembly A

  - Database.EDMX
  - Models.TT
  - Models.cs
- Assembly B

  - Database.EDMX (*[Added as a Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(VS.80).aspx) to the real file in Assembly A*)
  - EntityContainer.TT
  - EntityContainer.cs

That's how everything is laid out.  These are the rough steps:

1. Right click on the EDMX in A (public API assembly) and Add Code Generation File
2. Adds a TT to the project.  Called it Models, as it will contain the models only.
3. Edited the TT and removed code generation for entity containers
4. In assembly B (internal implementations) added Database.EDMA as a link
5. Opened in assembly B, right click and Add Code Generation File
6. Adds a TT to project B.  Called it EntityContainer as it will contain that only.
7. Edited TT to do the following

   - Removed entity creation steps
   - Changed the path to Database.EDMX to a relative path pointing at the original copy in A
   - Added a `using` for my models

Hopefully this will all compile and work correctly (I'm still far from getting everything compiled and tested).  Looks good so far.

---

Additional change:

In my entity container TT, I had to modify the definition of the EscapeEndTypeName to the following:

```csharp
string EscapeEndTypeName(AssociationType association, int index, 
    CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    EntityType entity = association.AssociationEndMembers[index]
      .GetEntityType();
    return code.CreateFullName(
      code.EscapeNamespace(association.NamespaceName), code.Escape(entity));
}
```

I'm using `association.NamespaceName` as it contains the correct namespace from the other assembly.

Comment: Does the API assembly contain only the interfaces? If so, you can add partial class declarations for your entity types to implement the interfaces (essentially a pass-through to the entity members). Then the API shows what's consumable and the implementation assembly contains the actual entities performing the actual work.

Comment: Interfaces, base types/abstracts and public types used by them (models etc).  I don't think your solution is practical; I'll be sending these through WCF and want to actually use the same models at the other end rather than generated proxies.  But that's still in the planning...

Comment: When you have some time you really should post the answer as an answer, instead of leaving it merged in the question...

Comment: @Bruno the answer isn't in the question.  Craig gave me the answer, and it is selected.  A little more detail of the answer--the EDMX had to stay with the model generator.  I couldn't add it as a link.  But for my Models.Context.TT I was able to edit it to add a relative path to the EDMX file, which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer, but I think that your question is essentially equivalent to "Is it possible to cause a T4 template in one project to emit code into a different project?" If you can do that, then you can do what you want. Note, though, that [this is substantially easier in EF 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx).

So I think you might get useful feedback if you asked that question directly.

Comment: I'm using EF4, btw.  I'm going to digest that blog post, as it does mention what I'm asking...

Comment: The T4 template doesn't like dealing with linked EDMX files.  Still working on it.

Comment: Works.  Thanks for the heads up on that.

Comment: Add'l detail--edited the context TT to reference the EDMX file using a relative path rather than try to add it to the project as a linked file.